# see "sent mail" with sendmail

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail

I have an application that sends email by relaying it through sendmail.

Can I see mails sent in the past? Are they kept somewhere, perhaps in the logs. I don't necessarily need the complete email, body, attachments, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sendmail does offer the ability to log every action issued on the service to a file, so you could check whether your sendmail version on your system is indeed doing that. If I recall correctly (it's been a while) it logs who (unix user) sent what to whom.